# Can't connect to database on notepad++

Tags: php, database, apache, localhost

I can connect to my database just fine when I'm on my website, but when I'm on my notepad++, and I tried to connect to my database, I get the error below. I have XAMPP installed, and apache is working smoothly, but the only thing is that I can't connect to the database while in the notepad++, and yet it works when I'm on my website. All the files are copied from my website, so there is no discrepancy between the files on my website, and the files on my notepad++. I use localhost to get to the index of my page using notepad++, and it works fine. Only when I tried to register information to my database did the error below show up. Please help. Thanks.

Warning: mysql_connect(): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in E:\xampp\htdocs\iscattered\register.php on line 3
Not connect :A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

```
<?php

$var = mysql_connect('mysql2.000webhost.com','username','password');

if(!$var){

die('Not connect :'  . mysql_error());

}

$database = mysql_select_db("database",$var);
if(!database){

die("Can't connect : " . mysql_error());

}

?>
```

Comment: Can you give us your connection code?

Comment: Make sure you've already setup a user with permissions to access that specific database, also check the mysql host permissions.

Comment: are you trying to connect from your local files to the database of the real site?

Comment: are you sure the hosting server is allowing this? usually shared hosting don't allow connecting to database from outside directly as this is a security breach that means that your database is reachable to everyone.

Comment: @lupin i don't understand. you can only connect to the database if you have the username and password, similar to how you login to the hosting server.

Comment: it is true that you  need a username & password but that only is not that secure, hosting servers usually limit access to the database only to requests that come from inside their network so the database is not open to the world. in some cases they allow remote access to the database but by using SSH connection.

Comment: @lupin I see. The only reason why I'm trying to write from notepad++ and not on the website itself, is because notepad++ is more organize, and also backing files from the hosting website I'm using is tedious as you can only download 1 file at a time as it's a free hosting website. But I can i can find a workaround that problem by making a file with a list of my current projects, so I can back each of the files when I finish working. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: @Deadooshka just got an answer from them, and lupin was right, they blocked remote access.

Answer (score 0):

Try mysqli..
somethink like

```
<?php

$var = mysqli_connect('mysql2.000webhost.com','username','password');

if(!$var){

die('Not connect :'  . mysql_error());

}

$database = mysqli_select_db("database",$var);
if(!database){

die("Can't connect : " . mysql_error());

}

?>
```

Comment: Same response from the server.